# Time Consuming SQL Update Statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

In Postgresql (version 9.2), I need to update a table with values from another table. The UPDATE statement below works and completes quickly on a small data set (1K records). With large amount of records (600K+), the statement has not completed after more than two hours. I don't know if it is taking a long time or is simply hung.

```
UPDATE training_records r SET cid = 
   (SELECT cid_main FROM account_events e 
    WHERE e.user_ekey = r.ekey 
    AND e.type = 't' 
    AND r.enroll_date < e.time 
    ORDER BY e.time ASC LIMIT 1) 
WHERE r.cid IS NULL;
```

Is there a problem with this statement? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

**About the operation:** `training_records` holds course enrollment records for member accounts (id by `ekey`) that are organized in groups. `cid` is the group id. `account_events` holds account changing events including transfers between groups (`e.type='t'`), where `cid_main` would be the group id before the transfer. I am trying to retroactively patch the newly added `cid` column in `training_records` so it accurately reflects the group membership when the course was enrolled. There could be multiple transfers, so I am picking the group id (`cid_main`) from the earliest transfer after the time of enrollment. Hope this makes sense.

The table `training_records` has close to 700K records, and `account_events` has 560K+ records.

**Output of EXPLAIN {command above}**

```
 Update on training_records r  (cost=0.00..13275775666.76 rows=664913 width=74)
   ->  Seq Scan on training_records r  (cost=0.00..13275775666.76 rows=664913 width=74)
         Filter: (cid IS NULL)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Limit  (cost=19966.15..19966.16 rows=1 width=12)
                 ->  Sort  (cost=19966.15..19966.16 rows=1 width=12)
                       Sort Key: e."time"
                       ->  Seq Scan on account_events e  (cost=0.00..19966.15 rows=1 width=12)
                             Filter: ((r.enroll_date < "time") AND (user_ekey = r.ekey) AND (type = 't'::bpchar))
(9 rows)
```

**One more udpate:**
Adding an additional condition in WHERE, I limited the number of records from `training_records` to about 10K. The update took about 15 minutes. If the time is even to close to being linear to the number of records of this one table, 700K records would take about 17+ hours.

Thank you for your help!

**Update:** It took close to 9 hours, but the original command completed.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Please edit to include the output of  `EXPLAIN <your query>`.  Which table has 600k rows, and how many does the other one have?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table `records`? Do you have an index on `account_events (user_ekey, type, `"time"`)`

Comment: The primary key for `training_records` is a field called `record_id`, not involved in the update. There is no index for account_events as you described, which would have sped it up, I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to transform it to something that does not force a nested loop join:

```
UPDATE training_records r
SET cid = e.cid_main
FROM account_events e
WHERE e.user_ekey = r.ekey 
  AND e.type = 't' 
  AND r.enroll_date < e.time
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM account_events e1
                  WHERE e1.user_ekey = r.ekey 
                    AND e1.type = 't' 
                    AND r.enroll_date < e1.time
                    AND e1.time < e.time)
  AND r.cid IS NULL;
```

The statement actually isn't equivalent: if there is no matching `account_events` row, your statement will update `cid` to NULL, while my statement will not update that row.

Comment: I will give this a try and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing! All was done in about 30 seconds. As far as I could tell, the records were patched correctly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Something curious. Before I ran the update, there were about 50K records with `r.cid` being 0, not null like the rest. The first run of the update statement completed in less than a minute, reporting 250K records updated among the 700K total records. Then, I ran `update training_records set cid = null where cid = 0;` After this, I rerun the update. But this round it took around 10 minutes to complete. Does this time difference make sense to you?

Comment: If you change a lot of data, the execution plans may change. Or worse: if there was not enough time for PostgreSQL to calculate new statistics, you may getbthe old execution plan for new data. In any event, you need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` outputfor the statement to understand what is going on.